# How to upload dsyms files which developed with Flutter?

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I am developing one Cross-platform app with flutter support. I Integrated firebase Crashlytics for crash reports. before I need to check report one error message comes

`Upload 1 missing dSYM required to process 4 crashes`

for that, I tried firebase docs

[Get deobfuscated crash reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports)

also, I followed steps to build iOS Archive with flutter

[Preparing an iOS App for Release](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)

Still, There is the same issue on firebase portal

`Upload 1 missing dSYM required to process 4 crashes`

I tried this many times but still not done yet.

If someone has Idea then please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks, Community

Comment: You should find `the Runner.app.dSYM.zip` inside the `ios` directory. It is generated by the `flutter build ios` command for release builds, assuming Crashlytics was setup correctly.

Comment: I also tried this but not done.

Comment: How are you generating release packages?

Comment: using On the command line, follow these steps in your application directory:

Run flutter build ios to create a release build (flutter build defaults to --release).
To ensure that Xcode refreshes the release mode configuration, close and re-open your Xcode workspace. For Xcode 8.3 and later, this step is not required.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Let your Xcode upload it automatically when you run/build your app.

I. Open Xcode > Targets > MyProjectName > Build phases

Add two scripts (using + sign) consisting of each of these

1. `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"`
2. `"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProjectName/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"`

> **Important**: Make sure to replace `MyProjectName` with your project name but leave rest as it is.

II. Also make sure to check these options in Targets > MyProjectName > Build settings

Set **Debug information format** to **DWARF with dSYM file**

III. Visuals
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I did exact same config as you but I still got the warning in firebase console... Any idea what can possibly go wrong?

Comment: NB: it's `"${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist"` and not `"${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProjectName/GoogleService-Info.plist"` (your screenshot is good)

Comment: @Milvintsiss The screenshot is an example of the project name "Runner" so that makes it relevant.

Comment: oh I'm learning something, I never did an iOS project without Flutter so I was thinking that "Runner" was like the "app" folder in Android and that it cannot have another name ^^

Comment: This no longer works, since you initialize firebase with the flutterfire CLI. Since no `GoogleService-Info.plist` is used anymore, I tried using exchanging `-gsp "[Path to file]"` with `-ai "[App ID]"`. But i still get the following error: `error: Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment`. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out myself. You have to add `-ai "[App ID]"` to the first script as well

Comment: Note that the generated "GoogleService-Info.plist" should also be manually added to xCode (click on Runner, then File -> Add files to "Runner") or you'll get "Could not get GOOGLE_APP_ID in Google Services file from build environment".

Comment: `-ai "[App ID]"` is the only thing that was needed in my case. refer: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter

Comment: For multiple flavors, what we need to do for fetching GoogleService-Info.plist file for different environment.

Answer (score 23):

When preparing my app for release I take these steps to export, upload, and get the dSYM's:

1. In terminal I run 'flutter build ios --release'
2. Open the iOS project in xCode and switch the device to 'Generic iOS Device'
3. From the top menu Product>Archive
4. Once finished the Organizer window will show your archived build. You can also manually open this window from Window>Organizer
5. Choose the build you want to upload to iTunes Connect and hit Distribute App and follow the process
6. **After upload is complete right click on the build in the organizer window and click 'Show in Finder'**
7. **You should see an archive file in finder, right-click it and click 'Show Package Contents'.**
8. **Inside there should be a folder called dSYM that you can zip and send wherever you need**

Comment: Right, but how do you know exactly which of them is missing? The name in the Firebase warning is some kind of UUID, but the filenames in the dSYM-folder are normal filenames of plugins etc?

Comment: That's right. I did it and it's work. but this is the manual method. Thanks a lots

Answer (score 8):

you can use `Fastlane` to automate also this as part of release process. 
here's an example that can go into your `Fastfile`

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Upload symbols to Crashlytics"
  lane :toCrashlytics do
    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics
  end
end
```

then you can run `fastlane ios toCrashlytics` to run it.

see [this link](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_symbols_to_crashlytics/) for more details.

Comment: The best way! Fastlane rocks.

Comment: Amazing, if Fastlane is setup then this is one of the best ;)

Comment: How do you do this for different flavors ?

Answer (score 7):

After building an Archive of your Flutter app (using Xcode), you can run the following command from your Flutter App's `ios` directory (using Firebase's upload tool):

```
Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios build/Runner.xcarchive/dSYMs
```

Change the above command line to point to the correct Firebase plist file. the `-p` flag specifies platform (which can be `ios`, `mac`, or `tvos`). The above command will also look for the App's archive file `Runner.xcarchive`.

Answer (score 4):

**OPTION 1**

I use this Run Script to automate the process

```bash
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE="/path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist"
    # (Usually "${PROJECT_DIR}/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist")

    if [ -f "$GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE" ]; then
        echo "Using GoogleService-Info.plist from ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}"

        # Get GOOGLE_APP_ID from GoogleService-Info.plist file
        APP_ID="$(grep -A1 GOOGLE_APP_ID ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE} | tail -n1 | sed -e 's/.*\<string\>\(.*\)\<\/string\>/\1/')"

        # Run scripts to upload dSYMs to Firebase crashlytics
        "$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" -ai "${APP_ID}"
        "$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --build-phase --validate -ai "${APP_ID}"
        "$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --build-phase -ai "${APP_ID}"
        "$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"  -ai "${APP_ID}"
        
        echo "Successfully uploaded dSYMs to Firebase Crashlytics!"
    else
        echo "GoogleService-Info.plist not found in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}"
    fi
fi
```

**OPTION 2**

However, if you're like me and you have build schemes for your app (like Release-dev, Release-prod, Release-beta); then do this instead,

1. Ensure you have setup your build schemes correctly, else the next steps will probably not work for you. PS: I use this [medium post](https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b).
2. Ensure you have GoogleService-Info.plist for each scheme in separate folders;
   **IMPORTANT**: Your folder structure should look something like this:

```
config
  |
  |
   --- dev -- GoogleService-Info.plist
  |
  |
   --- beta -- GoogleService-Info.plist
  |
  |
   --- prod -- GoogleService-Info.plist
```

3. Ensure you have enabled dSYM for Release builds under: Targets -> Runner -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> Debug Information Format. Should be set to `DWARF with dSYM File`

[image: Enable dSYMs for Release build]

4. Then add a Run Script with name `[firebase_crashlytics] Upload dSYMs to Firebase Crashlytics` (or whatever).
5. Copy & paste the below in the script section:

```bash
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
    environment="default"

    # Set the current build environment / scheme
    if [[ $CONFIGURATION =~ -([^-]*)$ ]]; then
        environment=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi

    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist

    # And here you can see why that folder structure is important.
    GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE=${PROJECT_DIR}/config/${environment}/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

    if [ -f "$GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE" ]; then
        echo "Using GoogleService-Info.plist from ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}"

        # Get GOOGLE_APP_ID from GoogleService-Info.plist file
        APP_ID="$(grep -A1 GOOGLE_APP_ID ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE} | tail -n1 | sed -e 's/.*\<string\>\(.*\)\<\/string\>/\1/')"

        # Run scripts to upload dSYMs to Firebase crashlytics
        "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run" -ai "${APP_ID}"
        "$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --build-phase --validate -ai "${APP_ID}"
        "$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --build-phase -ai "${APP_ID}"
        "${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"  -ai "${APP_ID}"
        
        echo "Successfully uploaded dSYMs to Firebase Crashlytics!"
    else
        echo "GoogleService-Info.plist not found in ${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}"
    fi
fi
```

6. In the Input Files section, add the paths for the locations of the following files:

   - The location of your project's dSYM files: `${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${TARGET_NAME}`
   - The location of your project's built Info.plist file: `$(SRCROOT)/$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)`

[image: Input Files section]

See [the Firebase docs for more info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter)

That's all!

Comment: Very nice, and I you could make it even simpler by just providing `-gsp "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}"` at each step and not needing `APP_ID`. FYI the -ai flag help states: `Provide your Firebase app id directly without parsing the Google service plist. This flag will supersede the -gsp, --google-service-plist flag.`

Answer (score 3):

Currently, a recommended approach is to add a Run Script Phase that uploads dSYMs to Crashlytics on every build.

1. From Xcode, select Runner from the project navigation.
2. Select the Build Phases tab, then click + > New Run Script Phase.
3. Add the following to the Type a script... text box underneath the Shell property:

```
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase --validate -ai <googleAppId>
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase -ai <googleAppId>
```

Retrieve your `<googleAppId>` from your generated DefaultFirebaseOptions file (appId) or from the Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> Your apps.

[image]

Taken from [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter Here's the updated source on how it's done. The link posted on the answer is outdated

Answer (score 0):

With recent version of flutter/crashlytics, adding

`-ai "[App ID]"`

into

`Runner -> Build Phases -> [firebase_crashlytics] Crashlytics Upload Symbols`

was the only thing that was needed in my case.

Full line looks like this:

```
"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --flutter-project "$PROJECT_DIR/firebase_app_id_file.json" -ai "1:my_apple_app_id"
```

Flutter 3.16.5

firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.9

Docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter