# Analysis crash info about the Flutter release app

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get useful info about the crash in the released app created by Flutter?

In the Firebase Crashlytics section can't show where the dart code crashed.

I found `App.framework` and `App.frameword.DSYM` would be created when `Archive` production app.

After run command below:

```
dwarfdump --arch arm64 ./App.frameword.DSYM >> ./xxx-dart-symbol-map.log
```

I found some useful info in the log file, something like this:

```
0x0006552f:   DW_TAG_subprogram
                DW_AT_abstract_origin   (0x0000b738 "CustomWidget.getCardFromBox")
                DW_AT_low_pc    (0x00000000002806e0)
                DW_AT_high_pc   (0x000000000028121c)

0x00065544:     DW_TAG_inlined_subroutine
                  DW_AT_abstract_origin (0x0000009c "_GrowableList.add")
                  DW_AT_low_pc  (0x00000000002808c8)
                  DW_AT_high_pc (0x0000000000280944)
                  DW_AT_call_file   ("package:app/screens/top/widget/custom_widget.dart")
                  DW_AT_call_line   (169)
```

I think `0x0006552f` is a ??? address of the `CustomWidget.getCardFromBox` method. But the Firebase doesn't show any information like above.

Bitcode isn't used.

Comment: how did you setup your crash analytics?

Comment: Maybe this is right answer，I will try later.    https://stackoverflow.com/a/58646345/9628756